# Convert complex SQL query to LINQ for rest api

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have two tables , one with accounts transactions and another one with account codes. I would like to get list of account names and its current account balance. below sql code works fine for me, but now I am moving to rest api in which I need Linq query.

Please help me to convert below SQL Query for Entity Framework LINQ Query

```
select 
    ac.AccountCode, 
    COALESCE(SUM(Credit), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(Debit), 0) as Balance 
from 
    tblTransaction t 
inner join 
    tblAccountCodes ac on t.accredit = ac.AccountCode 
                       or t.AcDebit = ac.AccountCode 
where 
    Transaction_Type in ('T_', 'P_', 'R_') 
    and Creatd_Date >= '1999-01-01' 
    and valid = 'valid' 
    and Creatd_Date <= '3/10/2021' 
    and branch = 'MAIN' 
    and ac.Branch = 'MAIN' 
group by 
    AccountCode ;
```

Any help will be highly appreciated, I need to convert exact query to LINQ as in my transaction table I'm using two column for credit and debit.

What I have tried, but says Operator '||'cannot be applied to operands of type 'string'and 'string'

```
var credibalance = from trans in aceMoneyDb.tblTransactions
                   //where t.UID == userId
                   join acs in aceMoneyDb.tblAccountCodes
                            on (trans.AcCredit || trans.AcDebit) equals acs.AccountCode
                   into alldata
                   from data in alldata.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   select new
                          {
                              
                              AccountCode = data.AccountCode == null ? "-" : data.AccountCode,
                              Balance = trans.Credit == null ? 0 : trans.Credit,
                      
                          };
```

Comment: So you have a requirement, which leads to some SQL code, now you don't give us the requirement, but provide the SQL code, from which we have to extract the requirement. Consider to edit your question and add the requirement: "I have tables of Transactions and TranscationCodes with a ... relation using foreign key ... Please give me those Transactions with their TransactionCodes that... Typing the relevant parts would also help

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse I have added the requirement

Answer (score 0):

This LINQ query should be closer to your SQL. Main idea that such inner join can be defined by `SelectMany` and `Where`:

```cs
var transactionTypes = new []{"T_", "P_", "R_"};
var startDate = new DateTime(1999, 1, 1);
var endDate = new DateTime(2021, 3, 10);

var credibalance = 
    from trans in aceMoneyDb.tblTransactions
    from acs in aceMoneyDb.tblAccountCodes
        .Where(acs => trans.AcCredit == acs.AccountCode || trans.AcDebit == acs.AccountCode)
    where transactionTypes.Contains(trans.Transaction_Type) 
        && trans.Creatd_Date >= startDate && trans.Creatd_Date <= endDate
        && trans.valid == "valid"
        && trans.branch == "MAIN"
        && acs.branch == "MAIN"
    group trans by new { acs.AccountCode } into g
    select new
    {
        AccountCode = g.Key.AccountCode ?? "-",
        Balance = ((double?)g.Sum(t => t.Credit) ?? 0) - ((double?)g.Sum(t => t.Debit) ?? 0),
    };
```